# Transition between C# code and HTML with "@:" is not understood in a specific Contoso University tutorial

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been going over the asp.net [Contoso University tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and there are two specific transitions between C# code and HTML markup (using "@:") that are not understood to me:

1)

> ```
> @:<td>
> ```

I've read that when ASP.NET sees the opening HTML tag it automatically treats the code as HTML markup. If so, why is the "@:" used here?

2)

> `@course.CourseID @:  @course.Title`

Why is the "@:" in the middle of the code line and not in the beggining?

The full view code is below.
Thanks in advance for anyone who tries to help.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <table>
        <tr>
            @{
                int cnt = 0;
                List<ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.AssignedCourseData> courses = ViewBag.Courses;

                foreach (var course in courses)
                {
                    if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                    {
                        @:</tr><tr>
                    }
                    @:<td>
                        <input type="checkbox"
                           name="selectedCourses"
                           value="@course.CourseID"
                           @(Html.Raw(course.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                           @course.CourseID @:  @course.Title
                    @:</td>
                }
                @:</tr>
            }
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In short,It is used to tell that render this text as plain html, do not consider it c# code.

In your specific case it is used to add space between CourseId and Course Title in View here:

```
@course.CourseID @:  @course.Title
```

`@course.CourseID` is c# code, when **@:** comes it is plain text now, then again when `@course.Title` comes it is considered c# code, so **@:** is to specify that it is plain html not c# code.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand you are trying to answer question number 2.
"@:" will do its affect from the point it is used to the end of the line. That means that  "@course.Title" will also be specified as plain HTML. If so, "@course.CourseID" should also be defined as plain HTML (which is not done).

Comment: it is answer of both your questions,`@course.Title` is c# code which should be executing that value of Title will be rendered, if you put @:course.Title, html will show on page course.Title as text not it's value

Answer (score 0):

1) You are right about HTML tags behavior. They could use `<td>` instead of `@:<td>`.

2) You are right also about `@course.CourseID @:  @course.Title`. It's unclear also to me why they chose to use this pattern. It would work the same if they used `@course.CourseID @course.Title`.

You may try yourself and see you are getting same results and output.

I would simply suggest you not take their example work as an absolute single way of using ASP.NET Razor.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Last time I tried to remove one of the "@:" you suggested - I got an error. I'll try it again and update about the result.

Comment: 1) When I remove the "@:"  I get a server error while trying load the page.                                                                                                                                              
2) I've moved the "@:" to the beginning of the line and it worked completely the same way.
When I totally remove the "@:" - It works, but not in the same way. This time I get the courseID and CourseTitle values without any whitespace between them. 
I still don't get the logic ...

Comment: What's the ASP.NET Razor version that you're using? About 1), did you remove the "@:" from both opening and closing "td" tag?